# SAS Macro Variable having commas to be converted to single quotes with commas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Could someone help me how I can get a macro variable updated with single quotes.

I am getting numbers as comma separated values from a Dataset like below:

2108008080, 2108008081, 2108888082, 2108858090, 213856345 etc 
I have to pass each of these records in a SQL where condition as Phone_numbers in (&current_macro_variable). To do this I have to add single quotes around each value as the Phone_numbers columns is a character field of Oracle DB.

Any help is highly appreciated. I could not get much help from SAS communities.

Comment: How are you getting the comma separated list in the first place?  It will most likely be easiest to add the quotes at this stage

Comment: What is your reason not to use double quotes?  Then the solution would be easy: `%let macroQuoted = "%sysfunc(tranwrd(%str(&macroVar),%str(, ),%str(", ")))";`

Comment: I couldn't find your question on SAS communities, can you please show where you posted it there?

Comment: @DirkHorsten Given the explained use case, I would guess this is being passed to a SQL box that expects only single quotes.

Comment: Yes Joe. Tom answer helped me. I tried 1C yesterday but not 1aC in my CATQ function

Comment: @Reeza my intention was "I could not get much help from SAS communities from the existing questions over there" I somehow like stackoverflow to get the answers than going to SAS communities. Ofcouse I did not mean to hurt you in case if you like SAS communities

Comment: @Naga, the majority of users on here are also on SAS communities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the `CATQ()` function? Use the `1` modifier to generate single quotes. Use the `a` modifier to get all terms quoted. Use the `c` modifier to generate commas as the output delimiter.

```
%let x=2108008080, 2108008081, 2108888082, 2108858090, 213856345;
%put %sysfunc(catq(1ac,&x));
```

Which produces:

```
'2108008080','2108008081','2108888082','2108858090','213856345'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom

Comment: Tom, one more question on the same lines I have. My actual macro variable is %let x="2108008080", "2108008081", "2108888082", "2108858090", "213856345"; When I coded something like below 
data  _null_ ;
out_str=catq('C1',&x);
put out_str; 
;run; 
2108008080, 2108008081, 2108888082, 2108858090, 213856345
This was the output
How did CATQ suppress the double quotes. When I used the same function CATQ in %SYSFUNC without _NUL_ step this was not the output. How is this possible?

Comment: You need to use A modifier to get all items quoted individual. But the real difference is that to the macro processor the quotes are part of the string. In a data step the quotes are required to let SAS know that the value is a string literal and not a number, or the name of another variable, or an expression.  In macro everything is a string so the quotes become part of the value.  So you end up with `'"2108008080"'`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `PROC SQL` and the `select ... into` syntax :

```
/* Build list of quoted phone numbers separated by a comma */
proc sql ;
  select cats("'",phone_number,"'") into :PHONELIST separated by ',' 
  from phonedata ;
quit ;

/* Then pass it into your Oracle query... */
proc sql ;
  select vars
  from ora.table
  where phone in(&PHONELIST) ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The quote function should do the trick.
You have to go through all of the words in the stringLine and add quotes.

```
%let macroVar = %str(2108008080, 2108008081, 2108888082, 2108858090, 213856345);

data _null_;
    n = count("&macroVar",",");
    length 
        quotedword $2000.;
    quotedword = "";
    do i = 1 to n+1;
        word = scan("&macroVar",i,",");
        y = quote(compress(word));
        quotedword = strip(quotedword) || "," || strip(y);
    end;
    quotedword = substr(quotedword,2); /* removing first comma from beginning */
    call symputx("macroVarUpdated",quotedword);
run;

%put &macroVar;
%put &macroVarUpdated;
```

Comment: `QUOTE` double-quotes it, not single-quotes.